# Looping a foreach in reverse, PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I am working on a minimal blog system in PHP that should work by scanning a folder for postX.txt files, then display each post from newest to oldest.
For a single blog post, this works fine:

http://pastebin.com/i3hiLWGd

post1.txt contains something like:

```
<?php
    $post_user="Frash23";
    $post_title="loltitle 2";
    $post_content="<p>lolcontent post 2</p>";
    $post_info="lolinfo post 2";
?>
```

That outputs a correct blog post.
The following code does not:

http://pastebin.com/HdtgMBPV

As you can see, it is the same code with an added foreach. Echoing $file1 outputs "post2.txt post1.txt", so why does this not work? All the variables (upon inspection HTML via chrome's firebug clone) are not working. (i.e. blog/users//.png).

Does someone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your code on here. That way your question might still be valid after the link dies.

Comment: Actually, I can't see much of this. Please post your code **here** and format it so it can be read easily

Comment: Also please properly indent your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

> Given a string containing the path to a file or directory, this function will return the trailing name component.

The "trailing name component", in your case is `file1.txt`, when you include it, you add `.txt` resulting into `file1.txt.txt`, which it cannot find.

Replace this

```
include "blog/posts/{$file1}.txt";
```

with

```
include "blog/posts/{$file1}";
```

Comment: Oh wow. I should've realized that. I used some of my code from an automatic menu craetor, wich didnt use file extensions, so i added them by nature. I guess that's what i get for coding the whole night.

Answer (score 1):

You claim that `$file1` does contains the filename **with extension**, then by using

```
include "blog/posts/{$file1}.txt";
```

You're appending the filename extension when it is not needed and the file cannot be found. try:

```
include "blog/posts/{$file1}";
```

Answer (score 0):

change this to

```
foreach (array_reverse(glob("blog/posts/*")) as $path1)
```

this

```
foreach (glob("blog/posts/*") as $path1)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants to reverse the order